# Paste data to excel with formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, web, datatable

I have a web page that have:

1. a table with columns & rows (using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/))
2. a "copy" button that will copy the content of table (including header & data rows) into a clipboard using flash. (using [DataTables's TableTools copy to clipboard](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/))

If I press the "copy" button then **paste to excel**, the data will be fit perfectly into columns & rows. But with no **formatting**.

I have looked around within the js file & the flash.
Looks like the correct way is to tweak on how to provide the data + formatting from the js.

Question: How to **include the formatting data** into the clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

Use range.pastespecial.paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

For more details look in the model reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839476%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: How to include that paste special into the code that generate the data for the clipboard?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't look at the Data Tables site. My trials showed that press on the button "copy" copies only the data, not the format. So you can't copy the format of the web-site to the excel sheet. But it should be easy to create a macro which formats your data  in a nice way. Use the Excel macro recorder and format manually the data and improve than your macro.

Comment: I wish to retain the copy functionality button, with improvement so it also include the formatting when paste. If needed, I would tweak the dataTable.TableTools.js or create a custom copy. But I still have no idea how to include the formatting information to clipboard. A sample would be helpful.

Comment: Please google yourself about the possibilities to copy information and/or format in the clipboard. There are plenty information. This forum will help you if you have a very specific question/problem